# status=bounced (mail forwarding loop for postmaster@localhost) when receiving an email with postfix

Tags: postfix, alias, mail-forwarding

I use postfix with the following `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = leibnizproject.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = leibnizproject.com
myorigin = localhost
#mydestination = leibnizproject.com, 197t.l.hostens.cloud, localhost.l.hostens.cloud, localhost
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_domains = $myhostname
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

When trying to send an email to `webmaster@leibnizproject.com` from `myPersonalEmail` I get in `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/qmgr[35735]: DC70314073C: from=<myPersonalEmail>, size=6508, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/cleanup[35745]: 01DA114073E: message-id=<398816530.4876742.1675349159274@mail.yahoo.com>
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/qmgr[35735]: 01DA114073E: from=<myPersonalEmail>, size=6643, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/local[35756]: DC70314073C: to=<postmaster@localhost>, orig_to=<webmaster@leibnizproject.com>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.15/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 01DA114073E)
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/qmgr[35735]: DC70314073C: removed
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/local[35756]: 01DA114073E: to=<postmaster@localhost>, orig_to=<webmaster@leibnizproject.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail forwarding loop for postmaster@localhost)
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/cleanup[35745]: 03F9A14073F: message-id=<20230202144601.03F9A14073F@leibnizproject.com>
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/qmgr[35735]: 03F9A14073F: from=<>, size=8633, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/bounce[35758]: 01DA114073E: sender non-delivery notification: 03F9A14073F
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/qmgr[35735]: 01DA114073E: removed
Feb  2 16:46:01 leibnizproject postfix/smtpd[35741]: disconnect from sonic309-24.consmr.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[77.238.179.82] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
```

Here is the content of `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
webmaster@leibnizproject.com postmaster
```

I've tried to modify some parameters in `main.cf` but the problem remains. I don't understand why the line `from=<>, size=8633, nrcpt=1 (queue active)` is in the log. Was a mail tried to be sent without sender?

Comment: Your `virtual` file maps `webmaster@leibnizproject.com` to `postmaster@localhost`. And you see in the log that this mapping is applied. Where do you specify that `postmaster@localhost` exists?

Comment: I thought postmaster was the name imposed by postfix. Sorry, it's my first mail server setting up.